# Terminating a long command and continue the script

Tags: python, windows, command-line, automation

I am developing a testing automation tool using Python that opens the CMD and sends a command through it to hear a sound out of the device. Based on that sound, the user can click whether the sound is there or not (i.e. pass/fail). Unfortunately, the command I am passing keeps running endlessly. I would like to stop it in (*let's say 5 secs*) which is a suitable time for the tester to determine whether there is a sound or not.

Most of the methods online either use multiprocessing exit which will cause the application to shut off completely, which is not what I want, because after the user determine the existence of the sound, the program needs to run another command that tests the LED light for example, or they use `signal.SIGALRM` which can be used with a timer that kills processes after some time but it's unavailable for Windows. What do you think I should do? If you can paste a code sample that does that, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you could make use of Timer from threading module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) . This is simple example:

```
import subprocess
import threading 

def terminate(process):
    print('terminating process',process)
    process.kill()
    print('done')
   

   
cmd = [<your command>, <your arguments>,...]


process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
kill_timer = threading.Timer(1, terminate, [process])
try:
    kill_timer.start()
    stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
    print(stdout, stderr)
finally:
    kill_timer.cancel()
```

It should work on windows machine.

Comment: That answer was brilliant. It worked for me! Thanks :)